# Fetch data nested relations eloquent with() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model file "Student" that contains the relation :

```
 public function implementations()
 {
       return $this->hasMany(Implementation::class);
  }
```

In my Implementation model, I have theses relations :

```
public function score()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Score::class, 'id', 'implementation_id');
    }

public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
```

I would like to retrieve a table with all its data.

I tried this

```
public function getStudents($id)
{
    $event = Event::where('id', $id)->first();
    $data = $event->students()->with('implementations')->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

It works. But I do not have the result I would like. I would also like to recover the `implementations` data with the`project` and `score` relationships

I tried that but it does not work

```
public function getStudents($id)
{
    $event = Event::where('id', $id)->first();
    $data = $event->students()->with('implementations')->with('project', 'score')->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `Event::with('students', 'students.implementations')` yet? You can eager load relations of relations using the dot notation.

Comment: It's work ! `$data = $event->students()->with('implementations', 'implementations.project', 'implementations.score')->get();` Thank you !

Comment: No problem. Posted as an answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `Event::with('students', 'students.implementations')` yet? You can eager load relations of relations using the dot notation.

Comment: I use this relation and I am unable to use eager load relation value inside the relation
$sql->with(['postable' => function($sql) use($is_detail) {
                        if ($is_detail && in_array(config('general.post_type_index.search'), ["postable.post_type_id"])) {
                            $sql->with(["postable"]);
                        }
                    }]);